# Change link name & image when toggle jquery expanded

Tags: php, jquery, toggle

I am using the following code to expand/collapse some text on click of a link

I need to change the link name to 'Hide' when the text is expanded and have a different image (i.e. arrow_up.png).

How do I do this?

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $divView = $('div.view');
    var innerHeight = $divView.removeClass('view').height();
    $divView.addClass('view');

    $('div.slide').click(function() {
        $('div.view').animate({
          height: (($divView.height() == 90)? innerHeight  : "90px")
        }, 500);
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
<div class="view">
  <ul class="moduleItemExtraFields">
        <li>text here</li>
        <li>text here</li>
        <li>text here</li>
        <li>text here</li>
        <li>text here</li>
        <li>text here</li>
        <li>text here</li>
        <li>text here</li>
        <li>text here</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="slide">Show <img src="images/arrow_down.png" /></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    //...

    $('div.slide').click(function() {

        // Update the HTML in this element
        var slideHtml = $(this).html();

        // Switch between show/hide
        if (slideHtml.localeCompare('Show <img src="images/arrow_up.png" />') < 0)
           $(this).html('Show <img src="images/arrow_up.png" />');
        else
           $(this).html('Hide <img src="images/arrow_down.png" />');

        $('div.view').animate({
          height: (($divView.height() == 90)? innerHeight  : "90px")
        }, 500);
        return false;
    });

    //...
</script>
```

Comment: And when the link is clicked again?

Comment: Thanks... that works good - apart from when I collapse it - it still shows 'Hide'

Comment: When I expand, its great. but when I collpase, it stay on $(this).html('Show <img src="images/arrow_up.png" />'); any ideas please?

Comment: I changed the string comparison to using `String.localeCompare`. http://jsfiddle.net/cjh5E/

Answer (score 0):

I would add/remove class to the div.slide to check if it expanded or collapse.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/uVPhe/) here

```
  $('div.slide').addClass('expanded');

  $('div.slide').click(function() {

    if ($(this).hasClass('collapsed')) {
        $('div.view').animate({ //expand
            height: (($divView.outerHeight() == 90) ? innerHeight : "90px")
        }, 500, function () {
         $divSlide.removeClass('collapsed').addClass('expanded');

         $divSlide.html ('Hide <img src="http://www.auto123.com/site/img/used/up_arrow.gif" />');
        });            

    } else {
        $('div.view').animate({
            height: '0px'
        }, 500, function () {
         $divSlide.removeClass('expanded').addClass('collapsed');

         $divSlide.html ('Show <img src="http://listedmag.com/images/down_arrow.gif" />');            

        }); //collapse
    }
```